# Django rest +vue.js excel file download corrupted

Tags: django, excel, vue.js

Hi Have problem with downloading excel file from serve by url. The file is corrupted etc..

below is my download function vue

```
        downloadFile() {
            axios({
                url: this.scenario.file,
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {'Accept': 'application/vnd.ms-excel'},
                responseType: "arraybuffer"
            }).then(response => {
                const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(
                    new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'})
                );
                const link = document.createElement("a");
                link.href = url;
                link.setAttribute('download', `file.xlsx`);
                this.myresponseObject = response; // this line is just to save  -  url= window.URL.createObjectURL
                this.blobUrl=url;                // this line is just to save  response object fro checking
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                link.remove();
            });
        },
```

in this code the url of the file which stored in the object scenario is -

```
 this.scenario.file = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/datafiles/Input_curves_bm7ionE.xlsx"
```

I have saved the "response" to look at it after download attempt:

```
myresponseObject:Object
config:Object
adapter:ƒ xhrAdapter(config)
data:undefined
headers:Object
maxContentLength:-1
method:"get"
responseType:"arraybuffer"
timeout:0
transformRequest:Array[1]
transformResponse:Array[1]
url:"http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/datafiles/Input_curves_bm7ionE.xlsx"
validateStatus:ƒ validateStatus(status)
xsrfCookieName:"XSRF-TOKEN"
xsrfHeaderName:"X-XSRF-TOKEN"
data:ArrayBuffer
headers:Object
content-length:"1345"
content-type:"text/html; charset=utf-8"
date:"Mon, 08 Jun 2020 10:24:40 GMT"
server:"WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.7.7"
vary:"Cookie"
x-content-type-options:"nosniff"
x-frame-options:"DENY"
request:XMLHttpRequest
status:200
statusText:"OK"
```

And url created by window.URL.createObjectUR is:

```
"blob:http://127.0.0.1:8000/8a40ab70-1ce4-42d2-9176-935c10ef1526"
```

Which is different from the original:

```
url:"http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/datafiles/Input_curves_bm7ionE.xlsx"
```

Guess it should be like this.
So, excel file downloaded is 2kb and is corrupted, formats or file extension is invalid

Spent day on it.....
Regards

Comment: Make a test: try to download a TXT file instead XLSX file. See the TXT file will corrupt.

Comment: Weird...the downloaded txt file content has my index.html content where I mount {% render_bundle 'app' %}. i.e. my main html file

Comment: Then try to download it manually (run the URL in the browser). If the TXT file is corrupted, your problem will be the backend (probably a route).

Comment: it is no corrupted, just nothing happens just white browser window

Comment: It's weird, because when you open a link to download, the browser open a dialog to save. Make a test with [this link](https://qs-mkt.s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/Materiais+Ricos/Planilhas/Planilha+de+DRE+-+QuantoSobra.com.br.xlsx)

Comment: I have found that something wrong in the backend. I click on the url link and get white browser window....Although in other applications it works fine